# Bypassing ethernet card with mobile 3g modem

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ethernet, 3g

i have a mobile 3g server. But I can't use it with my wired connection. In my workplace some sites(youtube, grooveshark or any kind of streaming sites..) are restricted. It's also impossible for me to work without wired connection. I want to use them both. I tried to edit my wired connection info by changing Automatic DHCP into Automatic DHCP(address only). But it didn't work.. How is this possible in Ubuntu? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the default gateway on your wired connection to the IP of your 3G modem.

Comment: No it didnt work out. In addition i lost my internet connection..